# Store Procedure Optimization & alternative to Outer Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SP.ProgramID  AS [ProgramID],                     
    FROM   Tran_SpeakerProgram SP WITH(NOLOCK)           
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 FirstName AS SecondarySpeakerFirstName, 
                                        LastName AS SecondarySpeakerLastName, 
                                        TSC.SpeakerID AS SecondarySpeakerId
                              FROM Tran_ScheduleProgramSpeaker TSC WITH(NOLOCK)
                                        INNER JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgram TSP    ON TSC.ProgramID = TSP.ProgramID 
                                        INNER JOIN Mst_Speaker ms ON TSC.SpeakerID = ms.SpeakerID
                              WHERE TSC.ProgramID = TSP.ProgramID 
                                        AND TSC.SpeakerID != TSP.PrimarySpeakerID 
                                        AND TSC.ProgramID = SP.ProgramID 
                                        AND TSC.IsActive=1 
                                        AND TSC.IsDeleted=0 ) SECP                                
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerExpenses TSE WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SECP.SecondarySpeakerId = TSE.SpeakerID
                   AND SP.ProgramID = TSE.ProgramID
                   AND TSE.TravelLogistic = 'Honoraria'
                   AND TSE.HonorariumType = 'A'
                   AND TSE.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerExpenses TSEA WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SECP.SecondarySpeakerId = TSEA.SpeakerID
                   AND SP.ProgramID = TSEA.ProgramID
                   AND TSEA.TravelLogistic = 'Airfare'
                   AND TSEA.HonorariumType = 'A'
                   AND TSEA.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerExpenses TSEL WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SECP.SecondarySpeakerId = TSEL.SpeakerID
                   AND SP.ProgramID = TSEL.ProgramID
                   AND TSEL.TravelLogistic = 'Lodging'
                   AND TSEL.HonorariumType = 'A'
                   AND TSEL.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerExpenses TSEG WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SECP.SecondarySpeakerId = TSEG.SpeakerID
                   AND SP.ProgramID = TSEG.ProgramID
                   AND TSEG.TravelLogistic = 'Ground Transportation'
                   AND TSEG.HonorariumType = 'A'
                   AND TSEG.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerExpenses TSEO WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SECP.SecondarySpeakerId = TSEO.SpeakerID
                   AND SP.ProgramID = TSEO.ProgramID
                   AND TSEO.TravelLogistic = 'Other'
                   AND TSEO.HonorariumType = 'A'
                   AND TSEO.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_ReconcileSpeakerExpenses TRS WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON TSE.SpeakerExpensesID = TRS.SpeakerExpensesID
                   AND TRS.IsActive = 1
                   AND TRS.IsDeleted = 0
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgramExpenses TSEV WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SP.ProgramID = TSEV.ProgramID
                   AND TSEV.ProgramExpenses = 'Audio/Visual'
                   AND TSEV.ProgramExpensesType = 'A'
                   AND TSEV.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgramExpenses TSED WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SP.ProgramID = TSED.ProgramID
                   AND TSED.ProgramExpenses = 'Deposit'
                   AND TSED.ProgramExpensesType = 'A'
                   AND TSED.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgramExpenses TSER WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SP.ProgramID = TSER.ProgramID
                   AND TSER.ProgramExpenses = 'Venue Rental'
                   AND TSER.ProgramExpensesType = 'A'
                   AND TSER.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgramExpenses TSEWF WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SP.ProgramID = TSEWF.ProgramID
                   AND TSEWF.ProgramExpenses = 'Wi-Fi'
                   AND TSEWF.ProgramExpensesType = 'A'
                   AND TSEWF.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Tran_SpeakerProgramExpenses TSEVP WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON SP.ProgramID = TSEVP.ProgramID
                   AND TSEVP.ProgramExpenses = 'Valet Parking'  -- This join does Time out
                   AND TSEVP.ProgramExpensesType = 'A'
                   AND TSEVP.IsActive = 1

            *                    
  ORDER  BY SP.ProgramID;
```

Outer apply requires optimization , Is there any alternatives to joins or how can i optimize this query. The bold one is causing issues making it 3 s time to execute . 
If i comment out outer apply it is taking 11 s

Comment: if this code works without errors then it should be on code review. --also dont repeat yourself 3 times which i suspect is so you get past the mostly code validation message

Comment: Why you need all the left joins and outer apply when you are not selecting any of those.. else post the original query..

Comment: What do you mean by "Outer apply requires optimization"?

Comment: And if you want accurate queries you should consider not splattering that NOLOCK hint all over the place. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Its not allowing me to post the original query . So i removed select statement columns

Comment: That outer apply query is a bit strange. It is using distinct and top 1, but there is also no order by. Why bother with distinct if only returning 1 random row? The predicates in that are a bit odd as well. You have TSC.ProgramID = TSP.ProgramID in the where clause but it is also part of the join. You have some other predicates in the where clause that should be part of the join predicates instead. Without the whole query there is little anybody can really do here. I think you could remove a number of those joins and use a case expression in your select list too.

Comment: 1. Give us some background about what this query is designed to achieve - so that we can possibly give advice on possible changes that preserve intended functionality. 2. Post a query plan so that we can review which parts of the query specifically are causing all the pain.